# StackOverflow runtime error on setter

Tags: c#, arrays, stack-overflow, setter

This code gives me a `System.StackOverflow` runtime error:

```
class blue
{
    public pawn[] p
    { 
        get { return p; } 
        set /*it points to this curly bracket*/{ p = value; } 
    }

    public blue()
    {
        p = new pawn[8];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well of course it does! You're setting the value `p` inside the setter for `p`. This causes an infinite recursion of method calls, which has the effect of overflowing the available "stack" space for executing methods.

It looks like you just want an auto property:

```
public pawn[] p { get; set; }
```

Or, if you really want an explicit backing field, then name it differently

```
private pawn[] _p;
public pawn[] p
{ 
    get { return _p; } 
    set { _p = value; } 
}
```

<sub>(Disclaimer: I absolutely *hate* underscored private variables, but this demonstrates the answer while making me feel slightly nauseated)</sub>

Comment: You should point out this creates an `infinite loop` which causes the overflow imo

Comment: @DarkBee well it's not a loop, but infinite recursion

Comment: @slawekwin point taken :)